# Using DidSet on array of Strings to have character limit doesn't work

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a character limit for a TextField which corresponds to a String within an array with the following code but it doesn't seem to work. The following object is a poll object where the user can add TextFields in which they can write in the option they desire. I'm trying to build a max character limit for each string in which if a TextField exceed the value of the max character limit, the array of Strings (or the violating string) is replaced with the old value. Right now, the print statements indicate that the values are being updated and fixed at the max character limit, but on the View, I can still type beyond the max character limit which is odd since the value in the TextField should be bound to the published variable.

```
VStack {
    ForEach(0..<newPollVM.pollOptions.count, id: \.self) { i in
        HStack {
            TextField("Option \(i + 1)", text: $newPollVM.pollOptions[i])
            .font(.title3)
            .padding(5)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(Color(UIColor.systemGray), lineWidth: 2))
                    
            Spacer()
                    
            if newPollVM.pollOptions.count > 2 {
                Button {
                    print("DEBUG: Remove row")
                    newPollVM.pollOptions.remove(at: i)
                 } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "delete.left")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(.top, 5)
}
            
if newPollVM.pollOptions.count < 6 {
    Button {
        print("DEBUG: Add Option")
        newPollVM.pollOptions.append("")
        print("DEBUG: \(newPollVM.pollOptions)")
    } label: {
        Text("Add")
        .foregroundColor(.green)
    }
}
```

```
class NewPollViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let characterLimit = 5
    @Published var allowSkipVoting : Bool = false
    @Published var pollOptions : [String] = [""] {
        didSet {
            for (index, pollOption) in pollOptions.enumerated() {
                if pollOption.count > characterLimit && oldValue[index].count <= characterLimit {
                    print("DEBUG: \(oldValue)")
                    self.pollOptions[index] = oldValue[index]
                    print("DEBUG: \(pollOptions)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func reset() {
        self.allowSkipVoting = false
        self.pollOptions = ["", ""]
    }
}
```

However, the following code works regarding setting a character limit for a single String.

```
TextArea("What's on your mind?", text: $newPostVM.title)
    .font(.title)
```

```
class NewPostViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let characterLimit = 180
    @Published var title : String = "" {
        didSet {
            if title.count > characterLimit && oldValue.count <= characterLimit {
                title = oldValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do  u assign values to ```oldValue```?

Comment: @uditha it's an environment variable within the didset

Comment: instead of ```didSet``` try using ```willSet```

Comment: Updating the same property in a property observer is undefined behavior when it comes to property wrappers, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, and looks like the single-string property falls into the former category, while an array falls into the latter one.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't what you asked for exactly. But I think it solves your problem in a better way. You can just use the `limit` field on your `UITextField`. Something like...

```
yourTextField.textLimit(existingText: textField.text,
                          newText: string,
                          limit: 180)
```

Here is a helpful [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-a-uitextfield-or-uitextview) that shows a good way to do it.

Comment: This question is about `SwiftUI` and not `UIKit`.